# accessing variable outside the with keyword in python

Tags: python

given this code example

```
 with lib.localcontext(example_context):
     x = 10
 if x > 0:
```

it looks like we're able to grab the variable x outside "with" keyword even though x is only declared and assigned within "with"?

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't scope variables to blocks, only to functions.  This is partly because there are no declarations, only assignments.